# Dump CPU registers from proc

Tags: linux, cpu, mips, proc

Is there a proc file that dumps the MIPS CPU registers ? I have to look into the contents of the registers on the go as I do some real time operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. The values of CPU registers change too fast, dumping them is just meaningless. Why do you have to look into the contents of the registers on the go?

Comment: Its just a doubt. What if I am executing the code line by line probably with a gdb?

Comment: When you're debugging code, your machine can still serve other requests such as a shell command or a ssh remote access. It wouldn't be able to do so if the registers remain the same value. Debugging line by line has nothing to do with CPU registers. Wiki 'context switching', 'cpu architecture'

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I thought about dumping the registers, just from the CPU register dump in pmem after the crash happens. However thanks for providing more clarity.

Comment: @ChenQi, when debugging code with gdb you are looking at the registers belonging to a particular thread on the machine. If the CPU does a context switch to service other requests, the registers for the thread you are debugging are saved and restored by the OS.